# How to fix Camera Instance Opening failure?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

After So long struggle. I found the Problem was unable to find solution. I have an activity with a button clicking on it initiates a fragment where camera is opened.  I followed this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) and also added code for create view with error logs.

P.S : I have already added all permissions.

```js
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);

        if(checkCameraHardware(getActivity().getApplicationContext())){
            getCameraInstance();
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), mCamera);

            //container.addView(mPreview);--->Remove this line
            //Add this line
            FrameLayout preview =(FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
        }
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }
```

```js
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

```js
//permissions

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

```js
//error log

D/tag:  C not null
W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
D/tag2: cannot get Camera Instance
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
W/System.err:     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:469)
W/System.err:     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:442)
W/System.err:     at layout.scan.getCameraInstance(scan.java:113)
W/System.err:     at layout.scan.onCreateView(scan.java:84)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
W/System.err:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:698)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/SurfaceView: checkGLSurfaceViewlLogProperty get invalid command
I/SurfaceView: updateWindow -- onWindowVisibilityChanged, visibility = 0
I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x6169bce0) (w:720 h:1280 f:1)
D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x623215a8) (w:720 h:1280 f:1)
D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x61daa2a8) (w:720 h:1280 f:1)
D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x61db12f8) (w:720 h:1280 f:1)
D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x61db12f8) (w:720, h:1280, f:1)
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x61db12f8) (w:720 h:1280 f:1)
D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x61db12f8) (w:720, h:1280, f:1)
I/SurfaceView: updateWindow -- setFrame
I/SurfaceView: updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
I/SurfaceView: Changes: creating=true format=true size=true visible=true left=true top=true mUpdateWindowNeeded=false mReportDrawNeeded=false redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=true mVisible=false mRequestedVisible=true
I/SurfaceView: Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x42481d80
V/SurfaceView: layout.CameraPreview{42481ad8 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-720,1118} got resized: w=720 h=1118, cur w=-1 h=-1
I/SurfaceView: New surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x42481e50, vis=true, frame=Rect(0, 162 - 720, 1280)
I/SurfaceView: Callback --> surfaceCreated
I/SurfaceView: surfaceCreated callback +
I/SurfaceView: finishedDrawing
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a2fcf8)
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err:     at layout.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:37)
W/System.err:     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:662)
W/System.err:     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:90)
W/System.err:     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:195)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2191)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.root.meeransunday, PID: 3179
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at layout.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:37)
                      at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:662)
                      at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:90)
                      at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:195)
                      at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2191)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

```js
//One more method Just to add detail
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {

            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        if(c!=null)
        {
           Log.d("tag"," C not null");
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("tag2","cannot get Camera Instance");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }
```

Comment: why are you calling  `getCameraInstance();` twice? in `onCreateView`

Comment: i did not get you.. Can you elaborate

Answer (score 0):

To use the following method

```
android.hardware.Camera.open(int cameraId)
```

You should pass cameraId, If you want the front camera Id you can use the following method

```
private int findFrontFacingCamera() {

    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            cameraId = i;
            cameraFront = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cameraId;
}
```

If the same camera is opened by other applications, this will throw a RuntimeException.
You must call release() when you are done using the camera, otherwise it will remain locked and be unavailable to other applications.
Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time for a particular hardware camera.
If this is not working let me know.

Comment: shoemessage ok cancel Method Not available can you plz pass that

Comment: this is not the issue I am not using marshmellow I am testing on API 19 and 22. Still I tested it. Not working

Comment: Let me check, I will check it again.

Comment: I will wait @shivam

Comment: Listen I found my issue. I was not able to correctly call camera.open. Therefore I directly Called Camera.Open in my oncreateview rather than calling camera instance method and I am able to open camera inside my application.

Answer (score 0):

Before changing facing of camera make sure you stop preview and release camera.
If you are seeing back camera and instantly if you call set facing to camera and start preview it will throw same error like "Fail to connect camera Service."

I have added both the function here to stop and release camera.

```
void stop() {
    Log.w(TAG,"stop");
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }
    mShowingPreview = false;
    releaseCamera();
}


 private void releaseCamera() {
    Log.w(TAG,"releaseCamera");
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
        mCallback.onCameraClosed();
    }
}
```

Put this functions inside your camera1 or camera2 api classes.
And call simply stop before changing and setting face like below code.

```
void setFacing(int facing) {
    Log.w(TAG,"setFacing: "+facing);
    if (mFacing == facing) {
        Log.w(TAG,"Same Facing return");
        return;
    }
    mFacing = facing;
    if (isCameraOpened()) {
        Log.w(TAG,"Camera is Opened");
        stop();
        start();
    }else{
        Log.w(TAG,"Camera is Not Opened");
    }
}
```